# I want to create a list in fragment (some thing like left navigation). But not able to populate the list in fragment

Tags: android

I want to create a list in fragment (some thing like left navigation). For this I used following code but not able to populate the list in fragment.

Main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment android:id="@+id/categoryList"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:name="com.example.fragments.CategoryListFragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

CategoryListFragment class:

```
public class CategoryListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code I was including a layout for header in main.xml something like:

```
<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>
```

When I removed it all things are working fine. Anybody can tell me how to include header?

Comment: I found this solution also. I used Relative layout for the same.